# Como tener acceso a una serie de elementos (tipo gridpane en mi caso) almacenados en un ObservableList

Tags: java, javafx

Tengo 5 GridPane que necesito hacer visible/invisible dependiendo de ciertas circunstancias. He intentado almacenarlos en un ObservableList pero al intentar acceder a ellos para aplicarle el método .setVisible da error, ya que al acceder al índice devuelve null en lugar del gridpane en cuestión. Ayuda Porfa :(

---

```
@FXML
private GridPane fila1;
@FXML
private GridPane fila2;
@FXML
private GridPane fila3;
@FXML
private GridPane fila4;
@FXML
private GridPane fila5;

@FXML
ObservableList<GridPane> mesas = FXCollections.observableArrayList(fila1,fila2,fila3,fila4,fila5);

for(int i=0;i<temp.getEmpleados().size();i++) {
    mesas.get(i).setDisable(false);
    }
```

Comment: Añade el código con el que estás trabajando para poder ayudarte. Te recomiendo que leas la guía para [hacer una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y reformules tu pregunta para que se ajuste a los estándares de calidad de la comunidad.

Comment: así está mejor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los elementos de la colección son perfectamente accesibles. Posiblemente tu error se deba a que intentas acceder con un índice fuera de rango, es decir, una 'i' superior a la cantidad de `GridPane` de la `ObservableList`. No sé que es `temp.getEmpleados()` así que yo lo llamaré 'elemento'. El bucle `for` sería algo así:

```
mesas.stream().forEach((elemento) -> {
    elemento.setDisable(false);
        });
```